# Decrypting SHA-256 with known plain text

Tags: encryption, sha256

If i have a SHA-256 hash and I know what could be the crypted string is it possible to decode it faster?

Lets say I know the string is formed like this : %d-%d-%d-%s
%d being numbers from 1-25
%s being a random string.

Is it possible to decode the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. SHA-256 is hashing not encryption. It's irreversible. You may however be able to try all available inputs and see if any of your known hashes matches one of the computed hashes. There is no other way than this "brute force" approach.

Comment: If you know a portion of the string does that not cut down the password space?

Comment: Yes it does, however if %s is truly random and long enough they keyspace is still too large for it to be practical.